# How to return a View type from a function in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a somewhat elegant navigation system for my App. Below is a function that attempts to return a View type. This does not compile with:

```
    func getView(view: String) -> View {
        switch view {
        case "CreateUser":
            return CreateNewsView()
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
```

The above results in a compile error: `Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Compile error for the above: 
```Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As of Swift 5.3 @hồng-phúc Answer is somehow right, just needs adding the @ViewBuilder Property explicitly.

```swift
@ViewBuilder func getView(view: String) -> some View {
    switch view {
    case "CreateUser":
        Text(view)
    case "Abc":
        Image("Abc")
    default:
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

Side note: Please avoid using String Literals. Better use an enum.

Comment: Sweet dude! This looks neat. I updated this as the accepted answer, granted that you are using the latest Swift UI version :)

Comment: @James you're very welcome, glad to hear that! yes, using latest SwiftUI :)

Comment: Hi, You have to write func below @ViewBuilder now

Comment: @AminRezaew That's not required, but I agree sometimes it might be nicer (depending on your project's code style).

Answer (score 6):

I managed to fix this by using the AnyView() wrapper:

```
func getView(view: String?) -> AnyView {
        switch view {
        case "CreateUser":
            return AnyView(CreateNewsView())
        default:
            return AnyView(EmptyView())
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using AnyView is a bad practice for the SwiftUI optimization, as per Apple's recommendations

Answer (score 2):

Making AnyView() wrapper

```
func getView(view: String?) -> AnyView {
     
   if view == "CreateUser" {
       return AnyView(CreateNewsView())
   }
    
   return AnyView(EmptyView())
        
}
```

Comment: Using AnyView is a bad practice for the SwiftUI optimization, as per Apple's recommendations

Answer (score 0):

You should return `some View`

EX:

```
func getView(view: String) -> some View {
     return YourView()
}
```

for more detail a bout some View, view [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/why-does-swiftui-use-some-view-for-its-view-type)

Comment: This would only work if `getView` always returns the *same* concrete type of View (known at compile-time). That's not what the OP wants, since he's trying to convert a String into a View with a `switch` statement

Comment: so we mean that adding `@ViewBuilder` is compulsory??

Answer (score -1):

I use the extension `.eraseToAnyView ()` to make func with some View easier:

```swift
extension View {
      public function eraseToAnyView () -> AnyView {
          AnyView (on its own)
      }
}
```

The final solution will look like this:

```swift
func getView (view: String?) -> AnyView {
         if view == "CreateUser" {
         return CreateNewsView().eraseToAnyView()
     }
         return EmptyView().eraseToAnyView()
}
```

I think this is the most concise solution.

Comment: Using AnyView is a bad practice for the SwiftUI optimization, as per Apple's recommendations